# php strtotime end of day light saving

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

Ran into an issue with strtotime() and time() this morning as the time changed back 1 hour.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$expire = strtotime('+15 minutes');
if ($expire < time()) {
// session expired
}
```

Between the second 1-2am period, strtotime was producing times that were less than time(), so sessions were expired on creation.  Why was that?

Answer (score 2):

`time()` returns the current Unix timestamp, which, by definition is seconds since 1st January 1970, UTC. UTC doesn't observe time zones.

You're setting the time zone to `America/New_York`, then using `strtotime()` to get the current local time, which does observe time zones, hence the discrepancy.

[UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) was specifically introduced to provide a consistent and continuous time reference. If you need to perform operations that rely on a consistent time reference, always use UTC.

FWIW, whenever I have to deal with time issues I set UTC everywhere (PHP, database, etc) and convert to local time in the presentation code - usually done by JavaScript on the client.

Comment: Thank you, great tip on UTC.  I'll be sure to make that update.  I'm sure that will fix the issue.  I'm just puzzled on how +15 minutes could be in the past, even if New_York was being used for the timezone, seems odd.